# Gradle Jacoco and JUnit5

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jacoco, junit5

We just ported our unit tests to JUnit5. Realizing that this is still rather early adoption with little hints on google.

The most challenging was to get jacoco code coverage for the Junit5 tests which we use on jenkins. Since this took me almost a day to figure out, I thought I share. Nevertheless, if you know of a better solution I would be interested to know!

```groovy
buildscript {

    dependencies {
       // dependency needed to run junit 5 tests
       classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M2'
   }
}

// include the jacoco plugin
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M2"
    runtime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M2"
    runtime "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0-M2"
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
```

Then the problem seems to be that junitPlatformTest as defined in the org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin is defined too
late in the gradle lifecycle phase and hence is unknown when the script is parsed.

The following hack is needed in order to still be able to define a jacoco task which observes the junitPlatformTest task.

```groovy
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals('junitPlatformTest')) {
        System.out.println("ADDING TASK " + task.getName() + " to the project!")

    // configure jacoco to analyze the junitPlatformTest task
    jacoco {
        // this tool version is compatible with
        toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
        applyTo task
    }

    // create junit platform jacoco task
    project.task(type: JacocoReport, "junitPlatformJacocoReport",
            {
                sourceDirectories = files("./src/main")
                classDirectories = files("$buildDir/classes/main")
                executionData task
            })
    }
}
```

Finally it is necessary to configure the junitPlatform plugin. The following code allows command line configuration of which junit 5 tags shall be run:
You can run all tests with 'unit' tag by running:

```groovy
gradle clean junitPlatformTest -PincludeTags=unit
```

You can run all tests which are missing both unit and integ tag using

```groovy
gradle clean junitPlatformTest -PexcludeTags=unit,integ
```

If no tags are provided all tests will be run (default).

```groovy
junitPlatform {

    engines {
        include 'junit-jupiter'
        include 'junit-vintage'
    }

    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results")

    tags {
        if (project.hasProperty('includeTags')) {
            for (String t : includeTags.split(',')) {
                include t
            }
        }

        if (project.hasProperty('excludeTags')) {
            for (String t : excludeTags.split(',')) {
                exclude t
            }
        }
    }

    enableStandardTestTask false
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rather solution then a question

Comment: It would be nice if this was separated into a question and an answer.

Comment: I agree with @PaulHicks that this should be a self-answered question. You can see the documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Also, the "too late in the Gradle lifecycle" issue should be [fixed in M5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/708).

Comment: this would have been really useful to me if I had found it yesterday! Someone else helped me to the same information fortunately.

Comment: for future readers (i'm not criticizing the answer, just sharing my "year 2023" find for those who stumble upon this 2016 question: "JUnit Platform Gradle Plugin (deprecated)" https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, so the hack now looks like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    def junitPlatformTestTask = project.tasks.getByName('junitPlatformTest')

    // configure jacoco to analyze the junitPlatformTest task
    jacoco {
        // this tool version is compatible with
        toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
        applyTo junitPlatformTestTask
    }

    // create junit platform jacoco task
    project.task(type: JacocoReport, "junitPlatformJacocoReport",
            {
                sourceDirectories = files("./src/main")
                classDirectories = files("$buildDir/classes/main")
                executionData junitPlatformTestTask
            })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can be also resolved with direct agent injection:

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'jacoco'

   jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.7.9"
   }

   configurations {
        testAgent {
            transitive = false
        }
   }

   dependencies {
        testAgent("org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.9:runtime")
   }

   tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
        if (it.name == 'junitPlatformTest') {
            doFirst {
                jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.testAgent.singleFile}=destfile=${project.buildDir.name}/jacoco/test.exec"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then report will be available with `jacocoTestReport` task

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference to the `junitPlatformTest` task, another option is to implement an `afterEvaluate` block in the project like this:

```java
afterEvaluate {
  def junitPlatformTestTask = tasks.getByName('junitPlatformTest')

  // do something with the junitPlatformTestTask
}
```

See my comments on [GitHub for JUnit 5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/475#issuecomment-242038043) for further examples.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to add @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) to your package

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class ClassTest {
}
```